# How to force polyfit with second degree to a y-intercept of 0

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

I've been using the `numpy.polyfit` function to do some forecasting. If I put in a degree of 1, it works, but I need to do a second degree polynomial fit. In some cases it works, in other cases the plot of the prediction goes down and then goes up forever. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import *

x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y=[100,85,72,66,52,48,39,33,29,32]
fit = polyfit(x, y, degree) 
fitfunction = poly1d(z4)
to_predict=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

plt.plot(to_predict,fitfunction(to_predict))
plt.show()
```

After I run that, this shows up (I tried putting a picture up but stackoverflow won't let me).

I want to force it to go through zero.

How would I do that?

Comment: this piece of code wouldn't run. degree should be 2 (for the sake of this specific example, and z4 should be fit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't need the fit's error be computed using the original least square formula (i.e. minimizing ∑ |y<sub>i</sub> - (ax<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup> + bx<sub>i</sub>)|<sup>2</sup>), you could try to perform a *linear* fit of `y/x` instead, because (ax<sup>2</sup> + bx)/x = ax + b.

If you must use the same error metric, construct the coefficient matrices directly and use [`numpy.linalg.lstsq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy.linalg.lstsq):

```
coeff = numpy.transpose([x*x, x])
((a, b), _, _, _) = numpy.linalg.lstsq(coeff, y)
polynomial = numpy.poly1d([a, b, 0])
```

(Note that your provided data sequence does not look like a parabola having a y-intercept of 0.)

Comment: Yes, I know it doesn't look like it has an y-intercept of 0 but the data I'm analyzing is things like disk Free on a hard drive so it's bound to go to zero sometime. Will this work? I just tried it for that data sequence and it worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: Another question, if I wanted to force something to a 100, in my case cpu usage, how would I do that?

Comment: Does not work

`coeff = np.transpose([x*x, x])
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'`

Comment: Convert `x` list into `numpy.array(x)` to fix it

Comment: this also generates different values than `numpy.polyfit(x, y, 2)` is this because the y intercept is being forced to 0? (Which makes sense. Just want to understand this more) How would you expand this to multiple degrees?

Comment: Would this give a 3rd degree polynomial?
`coeff = numpy.transpose([x**3, x**2, x])`?

Answer (score 2):

if anyone has to do this under a deadline, a quick solution is to just add a bunch of extra points at 0 to skew the weighting off. i did this:

```
for i in range(0,100):
    x_vent.insert(i,0)
    y_vent.insert(i,0)         

slope_vent,intercept_vent=np.polyfit(x_vent,y_vent,1)
```

Comment: [@kennytm’s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11596035/8729073) is quite fast actually.